# Is it possible to call database trigger from Java code?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-adf

I searched a bit and I found some info on how to call java code from database trigger but none about the opposite. Isn't it possible to call a trigger from a java method?
After inserting to one table (Table1), I need to create several rows to another table (Table2) from a select on the first one. I built the trigger but if I make it to execute after insert on the first table I get an error:

```
ORA-04091: table Table1 is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512:....
```

I am working on an ADF application, and as Table1-Table2 have a master detail relationship, maybe it doesn't allow inserting rows this way. That is why I thought that calling the trigger through a button may solve my problem. Any idea?

**Trigger**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Table2
AFTER INSERT ON Table1 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
insert into Table2
(
Select col1,col2... from Table1
);
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggers can't be called directly, they are only executed before/after rows are inserted/updated/deleted.

The problem is that in your trigger you are trying to access the table for which you have created your trigger, and that results in the mutating trigger error, because the trigger won't see the changes in the table.

**Can you show use the code of your trigger?** Why do you have to access that table? Maybe you could just use a stored procedure to achieve what you need and call it?

**Edit**

If you want to access the values from inserted row, you should just use the `:new` pseudorecord:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Table2
AFTER INSERT ON Table1 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  insert into Table2 values (:new.some_col, :new.some_col2, <other columns>);
END;
```

Comment: Yes thank you, this actually does the job :) And thanks for explaining that triggers can't be called directly.

Answer (score 1):

For calling your treatment you can create a PL/SQL Procedure/function and copy/paste (modulo some modifications) your trigger code in this procedure.

Comment: Can you help me with a procedure sample, I am a total beginer in PL/SQL :| Thanks

Comment: It is not complicate at all espacially if you already have a trigger. you have 3 blocks : DECLARE/BEGIN/EXCEPTION. Put your insert statement in the begin section and run it with todd or equivalent. Google "pl/sql procedure example".

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, no insert should complete until the trigger has been completed perhaps there is an issue with the insert statement?

Comment: thanks, but I made trigger AFTER INSERT... Shouldn't it be executed after insert operation?